# Low dimensional representations of the alternating group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory

What are the irreducible representations of the alternating group $A_n$ of dimension less than $n^2$ over the field of real numbers?

Any references, pointers, or hints are most welcome.

All the best,
Sebastian

Comment: Try the work of Gordon James, or the book of James and Kerber